# about invalid value of time

Tags: user-interface, time

GUI

```
try {
    h = Integer.parseInt(hhTf.getText());
    m = Integer.parseInt(mmTf.getText());   
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    Label.setText("Not a integer value!");    
}
```

1. How to do If the valid values for hour is from 1 to 12 and for minutes is from 0 to 59. If I enters invalid integers such as 3:60, it will display the appropriate message? This is what I do if I input the string such as S:rf ..
   then how bout invalid integer?
2. If I key in a string...it will show Not a integer value..
   but after that I key in the correct time...the message will still there ..
   how to clean this?

Comment: It might help to tag the programming language used as well. Looks like Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

This is from my c# code

DateTime time;
string timeStr = "23:00"

if(DateTime.TryParse(out time))
{
  /* use time or timeStr for your bidding */
}